# OpenMP loop parallelize

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm learning OpenMP and have some problems:
Parallel program slower than serial, i'm confusing (1 thread vs 2 threads)
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{       
    int threadsNumber=1;
    int S=0;

    cout << "Enter number of threads:\n";
    cin >> threadsNumber;

    double start, end, calculationTime;
    omp_set_num_threads(threadsNumber);
    start = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: S)
    for(int i=1;i<1000;i++) {
        S+= 10;
    }
    #pragma omp end parallel

    end = omp_get_wtime();

    calculationTime = end - start;

    cout << "Время выполнения: " << calculationTime << "\n";
    cout<<"S = "<< S <<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Results:
1 thread: **2.59876e-05**
2 threads: **0.000102043**

Where my mistake?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the reduction at the end may consume more time then you save using 2 threads. Perhaps a more complex calculation would give you better results

Comment: try `1000000000` instead of `1000`. It should return 2 seconds for 1 thread and 1 second for 2 threads. If compiler optimizations are enabled then use `volatile` variables to prevent optimizing out the loop.

Comment: One minor thing to add: there's no "#pragma omp end parallel".  Since you're writing C++ code, the end of the parallel region is automatically determined by the end of the structural block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As J.F Sebastian pointed out in a comment, you don't get much benefit from parallelization because your loop with 1000 iterations is rather quick. That means the overhead it takes to create a 2nd thread is larger than what you save due to parallelization. When you increase the number of loop iterations and thus give the threads more to do, the benefit of multi-threading becomes more apparent.

Comment: I don't know which C++ compiler the OP uses but if it is Intel C++ Compiler or GCC with optimisation level O2 or higher, the loop is replaced with `S = max(high-low, 0) * 10;` (where `low` and `high` are the bounds of the iteration range), which only makes the OpenMP version even slower in comparison.

Comment: @HristoIliev: [as I've mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167681/openmp-loop-parallelize#comment30064056_20167681) a volatile variable would prevent the optimization.